# Android Singleton, Prevent user from instantiating Class

Tags: java, android, singleton, global-variables

In my application I have some objects which were instantiated in the android `Application` and should act like a singleton. This works fine:

```
   public class App extends Application {
      private final Manager manager = new Manager(); //this is the singleton class
      //getters and other stuff
   }
```

now everytime when I need access to my manager class, I call it via the applicaiton context. Okay. Nevertheless, I want the user to prevent to create `Manager` objects. I want to make sure that a client can only access the `manager` object through the application context and not create own `Manager` objects by calling `new Manager()`...

kind regards.

Comment: you mean like a getter method ?

Comment: well, the point is, I don't want make the user able to create objects of type ``Manager``

Comment: This is not the best solution but you can check caller of Manager's constructor and throw exception. `String callerClassName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();` will return you the caller class, where you can match with you Application class name.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the Manager class inside your App class and make it private.

Then, only from within App can the class be accessed in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You should create factory method and use it to create the instances of `Manager`. **NOTE:** that the `Manager`'s constructor should be private.

Manager should look like this:

public class Manager {

```
private static Manager instance;

private Manager() {
    ...
}

public static Manager getManager() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Manager()
    }
    return manager;
}
```

}

There are many singleton pattern realizations. You can try to Google to find a lot of examples.